# Maximum number of subsegments in a circle array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, segments

There are n positive numbers (A1 , ... An) on a circle, how do we divide this circle into subsegments with sum greater or equal to m so that number of subsegments are maximum in O(n) , or O(nlogn)

eg :
n = 6 m = 6

3 1 2 3 6 3

ANS = 3
since we can divide the array into three subsegments{[2,4],[5,5],[6,1]}

Comment: Please give out an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is at least one number greater or equal to `m` in the array, just cut the array into smallest possible pieces starting from one of these numbers. Otherwise (and if sum of numbers is at least `2*m`) use a pointer-chasing algorithm.

This algorithm uses 2 additional arrays: `L` for chain lengths (initially zero) and `S` for starting indices (initially equal to own indices: 0, 1, 2, ...). And 2 array indices: `F` and `B` (initially zero).

1. Increment `F` while sum between `F` and `B` is less than `m`. Then increment `B` while sum between `F` and `B` is greater than `m` (but stop when is is still greater or equal to `m`).
2. Update arrays: `L[F] = 1 + L[B]`, `S[F] = S[B]`.
3. Repeat steps 1,2 while `F<n`. While incrementing `F` on step 1, copy most recently updated values to `L[F]` and `S[F]`.
4. Reset `F` to zero.
5. Increment `F` while sum of elements before `F` and after `B` is less than `m`. Then increment `B` while sum before `F` and after `B` is greater than `m` (but stop when is is still greater or equal to `m`).
6. If `F <= S[B]` use `L[B] + 1` to update maximum number of subsegments.
7. Repeat steps 5,6 while `B<n`.